# Filtragem de Dados em Api em Python

Tags: python, api

Estou fazendo um algoritmo em *Python* que faz um  get em uma url para cotação do dólar, porém o retorno desse get possui muitas informações desnecessárias gostaria de saber como faço para filtrar estes dados segue abaixo o código e a resposta da requisição.

```
import requests
import json

requisicao = requests.get('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/all/USD')
dicionario = json.loads(requisicao.text)
print(requisicao.content)
```

**RESPOSTA DA REQUISIÇÃO**

```
b'{"USD":{"code":"USD","codein":"BRL","name":"D\xc3\xb3lar Comercial","high":"5.3944","low":"5.3045","varBid":"0.0005","pctChange":"0.01","bid":"5.3237","ask":"5.3247","timestamp":"1606339799","create_date":"2020-11-25 19:00:01"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui você faz o decode de um json:

```
dicionario = json.loads(requisicao.text)
```

Você pode ir filtrando pelas keys do dicionário:

```
dicionario['USD']['name']
'Dólar Comercial'

dicionario['USD']['low']
'5.3242'
```

Comment: Como implemento isto no código?

Comment: Depende de quais informações você quer extrair. O exemplo que dei pode ser utilizado pra qualquer chave do seu dicionário. O retorno do seu request é um json com apenas o dólar, se ele retornasse outras moedas você poderia filtrar por exemplo: `dicionario['BRL']['low']`

Comment: Valeu conseguir  completar o algoritmo, valeu mano